# Rename [synapse] to [apache-synapse]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

There is a [synapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synapse) tag which is supposed to be used for Apache Synapse, but it's frequently misused for [azure-synapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-synapse), which is a completely different thing. Should the tag be renamed to [apache-synapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-synapse) in order to prevent this misuse?

Comment: There is already a tag [tag:apache-synapse] (with 0 questions). Hence, I think, we need to mark [tag:apache-synapse] and [tag:synapse] as [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synapse/synonyms). [Users with score 5](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synapse/topusers) or more can do it.

Comment: If it has 0 questions, the tag does not exist and cannot be assigned as a synonym.

Comment: Right. I think it existed the last time I checked. But it doesn't exist now.

Comment: The rename to [apache-synapse] would probably be better than the synonym, because there also is [matrix-synapse](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/matrix-synapse).

Comment: If we rename, I am sure that someone would recreate the [tag:synapse] in future. We should prevent recreation of [tag:synapse] unless "renaming" automatically does that.

Comment: @AjeetShah: The community can request that a tag be blocked on a site, and [a mod can escalate it for staff attention by adding the \[status-review\] tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/335251). However, we don't generally block a tag unless it pops up again after already having been burninated once.

Answer (score 8):

I actually went ahead and renamed [synapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synapse) to [apache-synapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-synapse) only to revert it back in a few minutes. There are a few issues here that need to be addressed before a rename:

- There seems to be a whole set of questions related to [Ararat Synapse](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php) that need to be retagged to [ararat-synapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ararat-synapse), unless it is actually the same as Apache Synapse. Would need someone with knowledge about that topic to weigh in here.
- There are a few questions related to [Matrix Synapse](https://matrix.org/docs/projects/server/synapse) that need to be retagged to [matrix-synapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matrix-synapse) instead.
- There were just a couple of posts that had "azure" in them which were tagged [synapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synapse), so I edited those out and renamed. However, there are a lot more related to [SQLDW](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-overview-what-is) which again needs to be retagged to [azure-synapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-synapse).
- There are a few related to the [SynapseFi](https://synapsefi.com/) API
- And finally [there are some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666932/regex-to-determine-there-are-no-any-special-symbols-characters-or-digits) that I have no idea what synapse they're talking about.

We can only rename the tag once all of these issues are taken care of. Fortunately, there are only a couple hundred questions so going through all of them won't be that much time consuming (however it does need someone with a background knowledge of those topics).

Comment: Yeah, I poked around some last night and there's definitely some cleanup needed

Comment: FYI the one you can't identify [has a comment by the OP that mentions Apache Synapse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27666961/6389010)

Comment: *A "few" months later...* If someone (I include myself) does this, @Machavity , are you happy for a ping, as Bhargav is no longer a moderator? I don't want to invest time if it can't be actioned.

Comment: @Larnu Clean it up and ping me to rename

Comment: Looks like there's quite a few questions on "Ararat Synapse" related to Delphi. I'm not an MRE, however, they are at least identifiable so I've created the tag.

Comment: Ok, @Machavity, I've done a good clean up, however, there are a number of questions that are tagged with [\[synapse\] \[delphi\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synapse+delphi) which I am not really sure on. No question I found mentioned Apache Synapse in the question though. I can remove [[tag:synapse]], but I can't add a new tag on them; do you have any thoughts?

Comment: @Larnu Probably need a tag for those [Delphi synapse appears to be a thing](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php)

Comment: Yes, several referenced the aforementioned [[tag:ararat-synapse]], @Machavity, but as a non-SME I could not say if Ararat Synapse and "Delphi Synapse" are the same. I could tag them [[tag:delphi-synapse]] without complaint, and then I suppose they can be made synonyms in the future if needed. Would you be happy with that?

Comment: I would go ahead and use the Ararat tag there (10 of the 12 questions are [already tagged Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bararat-synapse%5D+%5Bdelphi%5D+is%3Aq&searchOn=3)). It's always possible some might mean the Apache stuff, but I find that unlikely.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your input. I'll ping again once I've done that (going to get some lunch first though).

Comment: Ok, @Machavity , I *think* we're there. I think you're decision was on point ni the end, there were a few i'd missed from way back in 2009 that linked to Ararat Synapse, so it does *appear* that "Delphi Synapse" and Ararat Synapse are one and the same.

Comment: Tag renamed. I also created a [delphi-synapse] synonym for the ararat tag, just to forceclose on any future confusion.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Machavity